# DML operation Insert not allowed on Invoice

Tags: apex, dml, standard-objects

I am trying to insert a invoice record from apex code but getting the error **"DML operation Insert not allowed on Invoice"** . I am not sure is it some issue on permission level or salesforce does not allow it .
This is a sample code i am trying.Please help me if I am missing anything.

```
invoice inv = new invoice();
insert inv;
```

**Update** : I am getting the below error now =>
|System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Can't create Invoice in Apex. Use REST API instead.: []

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This object is indeed not insertable via apex dml operations, you may notice it from `Supported Calls` from [Invoice SOAP API Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_invoice.htm)

> **Supported Calls**
>
> describeLayout(), describeSObjects(), getDeleted(),
> getUpdated(), query(), retrieve(), search(), update()

as you can see, it it missing `create()` which is present for [Contact](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contact.htm), for example:

> **Supported Calls**
>
> ***create()***, delete(), describeLayout(), describeSObjects(),
> getDeleted(), getUpdated(), merge(), query(), retrieve(), search(),
> undelete(), update(), upsert()

It is not a permission level problem. It is not possible to create `Invoice` record in apex via DML.